# virtual address

Tags: unix, memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

Suppose I'm starting two instances of the same program. Will the text region of both programs have same virtual addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Depends. On most systems, if you run the same program twice in the same environment (same parameters, etc.), you'll find the same address mapping. This is simply because most of what the process does is deterministic, dependent only on the environment, command-line parameters, contents of files read, but not on changing data such as the date or process ID. This is very useful when debugging: if you restart your program, sometimes even after a small code change and recompilation, you have a chance that the memory layout remained the same. Of course, different instances of the program running concurrently may have the same virtual addresses, but they won't have the same physical addresses.

Some systems, such as OpenBSD, or Linux with various hardening settings, implement [address space layout randomization (ASLR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). ASLR means that each time a process starts, the virtual addresses of its code, data, stack(s) and heap(s) are determined at random. This is a security features, designed to make exploits of security vulnerabilities harder: the exploit code can't just access known code at known addresses. However, as ASLR becomes more popular, exploits also become more sophisticated to work around it. ASLR remains useful because it increases the workload for the exploit writer without adding a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but it's possible that they could. Each process has its own independent memory space.